# Integrating magento with direcpay payment module

Tags: magento-1.5

I am developing on magento 1.5
I have created a payment module for direcpay,but now i want to integrate that module of magento with direcpay site.I use this link for create a payment module.
[how to create a module](http://roysimkes.net/blog/2009/11/creating-your-own-payment-gateway-for-magento-part-1/) 
and its code can be found here
[code](https://github.com/radalin)

Thanks!